# Programmatically Refresh Windows Taskbar

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

I have a function that changed a registry value to hide unwanted icons in the windows task bar (tryOpenCreateKey is a function to update existing values or create the key if it doesn't exist, because Group Policies can do strange things).

```
public static void changeTaskBar()
{
    string subKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer";
    string setting = "EnableAutoTray";
    int setTo = 1;
    using (RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(subKey, true))
    {
        tryOpenCreateKey(regKey, setting, setTo, RegistryValueKind.DWord, subKey);
        SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); //Updates Windows Explorer with new reg changes
    }
}
```

If the registry value is set to 0 when Windows loads, all the taskbar tray icons are visible. Running this code correctly sets it to 1, but for it to visually take effect explorer.exe needs to be restarted.

In the 'Notification Area Icons' menu, there is an option to 'always show icons and notification on the task bar', which updates this registry value and refreshed the display for explorer.exe without restarting it.

I would like to be able to do this programmatically too. I have a similar function that unhides hidden files and folder which has to call a refresh to explorer for hidden items to actually become visible.

```
[Flags]
private enum HChangeNotifyEventID
{
    SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = 0x08000000,
}

[Flags]
private enum HChangeNotifyFlags
{
    SHCNF_IDLIST = 0x0000
}

[Flags]
private enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
{
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
private static extern void SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID wEventId, HChangeNotifyFlags uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

Is there a similar shell32 function (or other Windows API) to refresh the task bar and update the hidden tray icons.